# Convert keccak256(abi.encodePacked(idToSeed[id])) in python

Tags: python

I am looking for python syntax to draw the autoglyphs using python.

Here is the few lines which I want to convert in python. I am new to it. Please help me out with this.

```
uint a = uint(uint160(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(idToSeed[id]))));
output[c] = prefix[c];
idToSymbolScheme[id] == 0
```

Here is the code in c++ which I trying to replicate  in python. https://www.larvalabs.com/autoglyphs

Comment: What's `idToSeed[id]`?

Comment: Ismael Please refer to the below code. 
uint id
mapping (uint256 => uint256) internal idToSeed;
uint a = uint(uint160(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(idToSeed[id]))));
I want to convert it in python.

Answer (score -2):

The links below detail:

1. Keccak256 hash function in Solidity
   https://cryptomarketpool.com/keccak256/
2. Convert a string to SHA256 in Python
   https://cryptomarketpool.com/convert-a-string-to-sha256-in-python/
3. Pip install web3.py. Then use the classmethod Web3.keccak(primitive=None, hexstr=None, text=None)

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange. Your answers are being flagged as spam. Please read this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion